# display a toast in a GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a push notification client. I want to display a toast in onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) function.

and this is my code:

```
    public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
static Context c;
@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super("717816998404");
    c = this.getBaseContext();
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    String str =arg1.getExtras().getString("PVAL");

    Log.i("PVAL",str);
    // I want to display a toast here

}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("TEST", arg1);
    Log.e("TEST", arg1);

}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I want to know how to display the received message i trying to dispaly a toast to check the message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       h.post(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }         
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

How about adding the toast creation in onMessage method? Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
   String str = arg1.getExtras().getString("PVAL");
   Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If this doesn't work, then follow the Demo sample bundled in GCM library. The demo sample makes use of BroadcastReceiver in the main activity, which the receiver display a dialog message on the GCM incoming messages. You can change the dialog display into toast display instead.

Comment: example is create new intent but not allow to do issues with current opened intent's any ideas?